# increment NOT working in javafx controller

Tags: java, javafx

I want the program the open the next fxml file when the enter button is pressed. So I used a variable "count" to track that. The increment only happens once, and then it does not work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
Parent levelx;
Scene scenex;
int count = 1;
public void enterButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{
    count++;
    if (userEntry.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))
    {

        System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        System.out.println(userEntry);


        if (count == 2)
        {
            levelx = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
        }

        else if (count == 3)
        {
            levelx = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample3.fxml"));
        }

        else if (count == 4)
        {
            levelx = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample4.fxml"));
        }
        count++;
        scenex = new Scene(levelx);
        Stage window1 = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        window1.hide();
        window1.setScene(scenex);
        window1.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: if the increment only happens _once_ then that means something is not correct here -->  `if (userEntry.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))` , maybe a mistake in logic? does this part get printed out --> `System.out.println("YOU WIN");` ?

Comment: Yes it does get printed. Everything happens fine but its just the increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe javafx is not reusing this object, but creating a new one. Have you tried to make the counter static?

Comment: I will try that and let you know :)